# Is a table a true relational model?

Tags: join, graph

Here is an open talk about the table model. Is is a true relational model?
The table model is only a two-dimensional data structure, which does not contain association, and the relational operation can only be completed by Join operation which is high-cost for bigdata.
Maybe the graph model is a real relational model which contains vertex and edge. The edge connect the vertices and represent relations. So it is more suitable for relationship modeling. And we can avoid much Join operator using the graph model.

Just an open talk! Waiting for your sounds.

Comment: An "open talk" sounds like a call for discussion, and does not fit the Q&A format here. Also, the assumption that `join` is expensive looks like an unfixable flawed assumption.

Comment: well for most case in bigdata, the join is relly expensive as it need much shuffle and consume much network.

Comment: Proper indexing and data replication can alleviate those issues. All these models you've listed are in a sense "relational" because they _relate_ data to each other (whether as simple as tables or SQL-bound as foreign keys). Whether one is more performant or not doesn't change this. You might be interested in the concept of a [Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_theory), in contrast to a graph.